# MVC 4 Tutorial validation errors

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, jquery-validate, asp.net-mvc-4, cultureinfo

I'm following the [MVC 4 tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-4) and I'm having some trouble with decimals and date validations.

When I try to insert a date in format dd-MM-yyyy (because it is the format defined in the Culture I have my pc in) it returns this error: The field ReleaseDate must be a date.

Also when trying to insert a decimal field like 3,01 it returns a validation message: The field xpto must be a number.
You will probably say in these case to use a dot for this but in the culture i'm using that is the thousands separator like 1.000

Is this a general problem or it is just me?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "My PC" I assume you mean client side, the browser validation fails? See my article [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg674880(VS.98).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg674880%28VS.98%29.aspx) - jQuery moved the local specific files so you will have to hunt for them. For debugging 1. disable client side validation and verify server validation works with your local (ie, decimals and dates in your local). Then it's a matter of getting the correct client side validation. This is not really an MVC question, it's more of a "jQuery non-english date/time & decimal validation" type question. You might have to post this question again. Once you solve this, please post your solution.

To solve this quickly, create the simplest possible HTML page with jQuery validation that fails, then post the repro. You can look at the generated HTML from MVC to help you create a simple HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

You can change this behavior by setting the input culture: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.aspx. You can fix it on a specific culture or use 'auto' so the browser will use the user's current culture.

Comment: I tried to put a specific culture but it remains with the validation messages. It seems that it didn't affect the client side validation.